# Excel Macro find text and select rows from that to next

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to find this text:
"XYZ" and "*Report"

then select the rows from XYZ to *Report and delete all the rows including the selection.

I've done this:

```
Sub DelWordsCol()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)

    Do
      set c=SrchRng.Find("XYZ", LookIn:=xlValues)
      if not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop while Not c Is Nothing

    Do 
      set d=SrchRng.Find("*Report", LookIn:=xlValues)
       if not d Is Nothing Then d.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop while Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

' i can't use resize as the no of rows from "XYZ" to "*.Report" can be 8 or 9 or anything.
'I am able to delete the specific rows but not the range from "XYZ" to "*Report".

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your code whether you are looking for partial matches or not.

```
Sub DelWordsCol()

    Dim c As Long, d As Long
    Dim strA As String, strB As String

    strA = "XYZ"
    strB = "Report"

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")   '<~~ set this worksheet reference properly!
        With Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
            'shift one row down off the header row
            With .resize(.rows.count - 1, 1).offset(1, 0)
                Do While Not IsError(Application.Match(strA, .Cells, 0))
                    c = Application.Match(strA, .Cells, 0)
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(strB, .Cells.Offset(c, 0), 0)) Then
                        d = Application.Match(strB, .Cells.Offset(c, 0), 0)
                        .Cells(c, 1).Resize(d + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

If you are trying for partial matches then the [MATCH functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) can easily be changed to wildcard searches.

Comment: OMG,  you are the best. spent a lot of time on this. its perfect. Thanks heaps!! Can you help with one other thing. that if it finds the first instance of XYZ go to the next range and start the macro.

Comment: Can get the macro to  ignore the first instance of finding "XYZ" and go to next then do the macro?

Comment: You should be able to put a counter of variable type `long` in the loop. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i used your macro as is and works. so strA and StrB is set correctly and rows between them is deleted. but then I am left with no headers at all. so the macro should ignore the first instance of StrA and strB. then do the macro.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. I shifted the working area one row down to preserve the headers.

Comment: sorry another one can i get straA to hold two variables? so strA can be either "XYZ" or "ABC"?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785768/changing-word-color-to-red-based-on-list-of-words/33785911#33785911) for a method of looping through a series of strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you have determined c and d, then just use those two cells to define and delete the range:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DelRange()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Const lSrchCol As Long = 1 'searching column A

With ActiveSheet.Columns(lSrchCol)
    Set c = .Find(what:="XYZ", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set d = .Find(what:="*Report", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

If Not c Is Nothing And Not d Is Nothing Then _
    Range(c, d).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

You might need to use some of the other optional arguments in .Find for robustness, if there might be more than a single XYZ and Report pair in the column.

If there are multiple pairs, then you might want to specify your starting point, and set up a Do ... loop, exiting when c and d are nothing.

If it is possible for the first XYZ to occur **after** Report, you might need to also check to ensure they are in the correct order, else the wrong rows would get deleted.

Comment: thanks Ron for your help, but the range is between my data. so cant use this. somebody else has replied. thanks heaps.

Comment: @SaviPai The macro finds the row containing XYZ in column A; then the next row containing Report; and deletes all the rows from and including one to the next.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: my mistake should have made it clear. sorry new to forum. these are headers as a result of converting a report to excel. eg; cell A1 has "XYZ "cell A7 has "Report" (Junk). then A8: A15 tables(good data). A16: A22 junk then data. so on.. I had to find the rows between "XYZ" to "Report". delete, then go to next. thanks so much though. Now i have the code except that I need the macro to leave the first instance of the search. and start macro after that.