# Changing word color to red based on list of words

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which allows me to change one word to a different color. Is there a way to change multiple words to different colors so I don't have to set up the macro for 100 different words, and then run the macro 100 different times?

For example - this is the code when searching for word 'dog'. Can I also add in 'cat' somehow?

```
Sub test()
    Dim changeRange As Range, oneCell As Range
    Dim testStr As String, seekstr As String
    Dim startPosition As String
    seekstr = "dog": Rem adjust

    Set changeRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B21"): Rem adjust

    For Each oneCell In changeRange.Cells
        testStr = CStr(oneCell.Value)
        testStr = LCase(testStr): seekstr = LCase(seekstr): Rem For Case insensitive

        oneCell.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic: Rem remove all colors

        startPosition = 1
        Do While 0 < InStr(startPosition, " " & testStr & " ", " " & seekstr & " ", 1)
            startPosition = InStr(startPosition, " " & testStr & " ", " " & seekstr & " ") + 1
            oneCell.Characters(startPosition - 1, Len(seekstr)).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        Loop

    Next oneCell
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use an Array that holds all the words you want to look for.  Or, if you have this list in Excel, you can use that list, throw into an array, then loop through the array and cells.  Also, I don't know, but perhaps Conditional Formatting would be a good bet too - I just don't know if you can have 100 conditions :P

Comment: @pnuts - I misread and didn't realize it was to color a single word out of many, d'oh!

Answer (score 2):

Work with an array of pets. After getting to each individual cell, cycle through the array, testing each value and adjusting the text color as necessary.

```
Sub test()
    Dim changeRange As Range, oneCell As Range
    Dim testStr As String, seekstr As String
    Dim startPosition As String
    Dim v As Long, vPETs As Variant

    vPETs = Array("dog", "cat", "hamster")

    Set changeRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B21"): Rem adjust

    For Each oneCell In changeRange.Cells
        testStr = CStr(oneCell.Value)
        testStr = LCase(testStr): seekstr = LCase(seekstr): Rem For Case insensitive

        oneCell.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic: Rem remove all colors

        For v = LBound(vPETs) To UBound(vPETs)
            seekstr = vPETs(v)
            startPosition = 1
            Do While 0 < InStr(startPosition, " " & testStr & " ", " " & seekstr & " ", 1)
                startPosition = InStr(startPosition, " " & testStr & " ", " " & seekstr & " ") + 1
                oneCell.Characters(startPosition - 1, Len(seekstr)).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Loop
        Next v

    Next oneCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to ask - do you know if a conditional format (set up via VBA, since it'd be easier I think) that could hold essentially an `Or()` formula looking for the 100 names?  That way it could be set up and be dynamic, so if anything changes, the colors would too. I just don't know the upper limit to Conditional Formatting's condition amount.

Comment: You cannot set part of a string to different font color the way that this sub is doing with a CF rule. However, it would be simple enough to enact it with a Worksheet_Change. Single cell changes wouldn't even be noticeable and I haven't met too many people that cannot pause for a second to let a large bulk paste process.